# JavaScript: Loop Function runs twice when called

Tags: javascript, html, loops, easeljs, createjs

I have a function that loops 5 times to create and add some playcard to the stage.
The problem is when I call the function the code is executed twice.
I look im my programm after where the function is utilized and I am sure that it is called only once.

This is the function:

```
var f = function (f, cnt) 
    {

        var cardverso = new skillpokerjs.CardVerso(images,cnt);
        var karte3 = cardverso.returnCardVerso();

        this.verso_karten_container[cnt] = karte3;

        karte3.setTransform(((cnt * cardverso.getWidth() + 600) ) + (10 * cnt),        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);

       createjs.Tween.get(karte3).wait(500).to({scaleX:.6, scaleY:.6,alpha:1}, 1500,        createjs.Ease.bounceOut);
       this._stage.addChild(karte3);

       if (cnt-- > 0) 
       {
        createjs.Tween.get().wait(100).call(f, [f, cnt], this);
       }

   };

createjs.Tween.get().wait(2000).call(f, [f, 4],this);
```

I tried to reproduce this error with JSFiddle and the code is executed twice only when the function is called twice, obviously. You can have a look at it here: [**link to JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/VTLTX/6/)

I hope you can find something.
Thanky you for your time.

Comment: seems fine to me unless I don't actually understand the question. In ur fiddle you're invoking the last line of code twice

Comment: Yes, with JSFiddle I tried to reproduce the error I get in my programm and the only way to get the same results is to call the function twice. In my programm I do not call the function twice and I get the results as I would do so. 
The IDE I use is WebStorm from JetBrains and this IDE gives you the possibility to see where a function is utilized in your code and in my code this function is called only once.

Comment: so in fiddle it works fine but not in your IDE?

Comment: Yes in fiddle it works fine but not in my programm

Comment: This is gonna be a tricky one to solve as we can't actually see the problem on fiddle

Comment: you don't need to pass in the function as an arg to the same function, perhaps remove that and it might become clearer.

Comment: ie http://jsfiddle.net/Wz46T/

Comment: Hi @Niall, your ideea is good and I tried it in my programm. Now I get only a card on the stage and the code is still executed twice. The compiler says that the cnt (count) in my programm is undefined. I did it just like you in JSFiddle and the code works there perfectly.

Comment: @deLuna are you now definitely passing in only one argument?

Comment: @Niall Yes only one argument

Comment: @Niall I think your solution is good but probably the error is not in this part of code i posted here. I am still searching for the error.
When I have something I will let you know.

Comment: I found the error. On the server side this function was called from the same user 2 times because I had the twice in my userlist. There was the error and I was searsching for it on the client side.
Thank you all for your time and help.